# Is it possible to have under Kubernetes the Pod hostname be the hosting Node hostname?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Moving from Docker to K8s, today we run some containers with:
**docker run --hostname %H ...** that causes the container to get the Host machine hostname as its own, can I have similar behavior running under K8s? (having the pod hostname as the Node hostname)

From what I have seen so far:

1. spec.hostname seems not to support values from env vars.
2. Using hostAliases seems to put a hardcoded name...

BTW, the pods are deployed as a DeamonSet

Comment: I would encourage you to read about statefulsets wherein you can specify a prefix which you would want the pods should have. This will, of course, will be preceded by an ordinal which the machine assigns.

Comment: @RaunakJhawar Thanks! but this is running now as a DeamonSet (as I need it to run all the time and one instance per node), if can stay with the DeamonSet it is best.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `hostNetwork: true` for pod's spec, it will share the network with the node. Here is a simple test:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv HOSTNAME
          sleep 10;
        done;
  restartPolicy: Never
```

That shows that the pod's host name is the same as its node.

Note though that this setup is general [not recommended](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/):

> Avoid using `hostNetwork`, for the same reasons as `hostPort`

However, maybe in your case that's not an issue.